# ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE работает не правильно

Tags: mysql, база-данных

**Есть MySQL версии 5.7.**

Есть таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table` (
  `id`            INT UNSIGNED  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `name`          TEXT      NOT NULL,
  `description`   TEXT      NOT NULL,
  `login`         TEXT      NOT NULL,
  `password`      TEXT      NOT NULL,
  `old_passwords` TEXT      NOT NULL,
  `last_update`   TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `created`       TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

Есть запрос с обновлением в случае совпадения:

```
INSERT INTO `table` (name, description, login, password, old_passwords, last_update, created)
VALUES ("name", "description", "login", "pass", "oldPasswords", CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = "n", description = "d", login = "l", password = "p", old_passwords = "oldp", last_update = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

*Вопрос, а чего он не работает то? Почему каждый раз создаётся новая запись и не обновляется старая, как это исправить?*

UPDATE:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table` (
  `id`            INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `name`          TEXT         NOT NULL,
  `description`   TEXT         NOT NULL,
  `login`         TEXT         NOT NULL,
  `password`      TEXT         NOT NULL,
  `old_passwords` TEXT         NOT NULL,
  `last_update`   TIMESTAMP    NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `created`       TIMESTAMP    NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  UNIQUE (id)
);

INSERT INTO `table` (id, name, description, login, password, old_passwords, last_update, created)
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  name          = ?,
  description   = ?,
  login         = ?,
  password      = ?,
  old_passwords = ?,
  last_update   = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Вот так как бы работает.

Comment: а где в таблице UNIQUE-индексы?

Comment: Это программа аля PasswordManager, для домашнего пользования. В ней может быть изменено абсолютно любое поле, ибо к примеру я заведу новый аккаунт в каком либо сервисе - соответственно и логин будет изменен. Как по мне то только id может быть уникальным.

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы при запросе если указанный id уже есть, то обновить его, а если нет, то внести новую запись. Но я не знаю как правильно такое реализовать.

Comment: Дык, ты же в запросе id не указываешь, вот новый и создаётся каждый раз... а в остальном с виду всё правильно... ЗЫ: стоит упоминать людей при ответе...

Comment: Оно же не зря ***ON DUPLICATE** KEY UPDATE*! То есть чтобы оно сработало, нужен дубликат. А дубликат с точки зрения сервера - это значение, которое нарушает требование уникального индекса, других смыслов нет. Если нет уникального индекса - нарушать нечего, и `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` не сработает никогда.

Comment: @Prototype-TV вместо UNIQUE (id) пишете UNIQUE (`name`, `login`).

Comment: @Prototype-TV Можно, сделать как написал Александр Белинский, можно следующим способом (немного длиннее) https://pastebin.com/pvaxFJBY

Comment: @Bleser спасибо за пример, скоро его протестирую. Что же касается индексов я вспомнил, что в MySQL нет if exists и нельзя проверить есть ли уже индекс, а программа будет создавать его каждый раз при запуске(точнее будет пытаться это делать), тем самым вызывая ошибку. Так же знаю по одному из своих вопросов то, что проверить существует ли индекс - это геморрой я больше склоняюсь к ответ Александра.

Comment: @АлександрБелинский у меня JavaFX приложение(локальное, для домашнего пользования) файлик бд будет храниться там же откуда и запуск, поэтому проверяться (и если надо - создаваться) таблица будет каждый раз, а если делать с индеком, то на повторное создание он кинет исключение, но это я могу обойти проверив вручную есть ли файл с бд или нет)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75987/discussion-on-question-by-prototype-tv-on-duplicate-key-update---).